# but rep just said where is the evidence

Tags: word-meaning

(The message quoted below is disputed)

What does "rep" stand for here? Representative? Republican?

> Amy Sweet tweeted 11h ago in Replying to @TeamTrump
> We just showed them the video of them telling everyone to leave but then when coast was clear 4 pulled out suitcases and counted for 2 hours **but rep just said where is the evidence**!!! You could show her someone being murdered on camera and they would say where’s the evidence!!

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TeamTrump/status/1334569329334083586)

Comment: The Twitter string from which the quote comes makes no reference to any particular person or party. I am not a twitterer or familiar with its jargon. It's not clear to me but it may refer to a **reply** .

Comment: Note that Twitter has a hard character limit, leading people to shorten or remove many words to fit in everything they want to say. As a result, tweets should not be taken as an example of correct writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rep#English) shows five meanings of "rep":

> (informal) Clipping of reputation.
> (weightlifting, countable) Clipping of repetition.
> (informal) Clipping of representative.
> (theater) Clipping of repertory.
> (military, in combination) Clipping of report.

It almost certainly means "representative" here.

Notice that the tweeter is dropping articles: "when (the) coast was clear".

An expanded phrasing would be "but *the* rep*resentative* just said "where is the evidence"!!!